# Asymptotics of Oscillatory Integral: Is the Limit Zero?

Tags: limits, definite-integrals, fourier-analysis, asymptotics

Consider the following integral, for $\epsilon\ne 0:$

$$\displaystyle\frac{1}{(2\pi)^2\epsilon^4}\int_{\Omega}yb\,e^{\frac{i}{\epsilon}[-ay+bx-yb]}\,dx\,da\,dy\,db\,,$$

where $\Omega$ is some compact neighborhood of the origin. The exponent $-ay+bx-yb$ has a nondegenerate and unique critical point at $(x,a,y,b)=(0,0,0,0)\,,$
and therefore the stationary phase approximation says that

$$\displaystyle\lim\limits_{\epsilon\to 0}\frac{1}{(2\pi)^2\epsilon^2}\int_{\Omega}yb\,e^{\frac{i}{\epsilon}[-ay+bx-yb]}\,dx\,da\,dy\,db=0\,.$$

My guess is that it's also true that
$$\lim\limits_{\epsilon\to 0}\frac{1}{(2\pi)^2\epsilon^4}\int_{\Omega}yb\,e^{\frac{i}{\epsilon}[-ay+bx-yb]}\,dx\,da\,dy\,db=0\,,$$

but I'm not sure how to show it. Does anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: @joriki Thank you, I fixed it.